# Aplicar CSS quando duas classes estiverem juntas

Tags: html, css

Como aplicar uma configuracao de CSS apenas quando uma tag estiver com as classes *nome1* e *nome2* ao mesmo tempo?

Eu tentei com o seguinte código, mas não está funcionando. Alguém sabe como fazer?

```css
.nome1 {
  color: black;
}

.nome2 {
  color: blue;
}

.nome3 {
  color: green;
}

.nome1 .nome2 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="nome1">
  Nome1
</div>
<div class="nome2">
  Nome2
</div>
<div class="nome3">
  Nome3
</div>
<div class="nome1 nome2">
  Nome1 e Nome2
</div>
```

Comment: Segundo os critérios do W3Schools.com você está quase certo, entretando você adicionou aos dois 2 cores diferentes, por tanto deu conflito, consulte nesse link:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_class_more2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O código original está quase certo. O que faz a diferença é que quando tem um espaço na definição do estilo do `CSS` (`.nome1 .nome2`) está definindo que o estilo será aplicado para a classe `nome1` **E** `nome2`. Você pode definir uma regra usando mais de um atributo apenas removendo os espaços entre as definições (`.nome1.nome2`). O resultado é o seguinte:

```
.nome1.nome2 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

---

**Referências:**

- [CSS rule to apply only if element has BOTH classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5796669/3388148);
- [Defining A CSS Selector That Requires A Multi-Class Union](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/680-defining-a-css-selector-that-requires-a-multi-class-union.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Você chegou quase na resposta.. ao invés de declarar as duas classes de forma separada (`.nome1 .nome2`), junta elas na declaração no css:

```
.nome1.nome2 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Quando você coloca `.nome1 .nome2`, na verdade está dizendo que vai ser aplicado nos filhos de `nome1` que são `nome2`

`.nome1.nome2` é o certo

Comment: Depois de quase 4 anos esperava ver uma resposta diferente das outras...